# How to push a controller upon performing an action using ESTabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

I've implemented a tab bar using ESTabBarController. So far I've managed make the middle tab launch a modal and upon clicking "Add" my app creates a new entry. What I'm struggling is to make a transition to the Analytics controller right after the entry is made.

Here is my code. It lives in `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
 let tabBarController = ESTabBarController()
 tabBarController.delegate = self



 let v1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QueryViewController") as! QueryViewController
 let v2 = QueryViewController()
 let v3 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController") as! SettingsViewController

 v1.tabBarItem   = ESTabBarItem.init(TabBarContentView())
 v2.tabBarItem   = ESTabBarItem.init(TabBarContentView())
 v3.tabBarItem   = ESTabBarItem.init(TabBarContentView())

 v1.tabBarItem.image = UIImage.init(named: "ic_home")
 v2.tabBarItem.image = UIImage.init(named: "ic_new")
 v3.tabBarItem.image = UIImage.init(named: "ic_settings")

 v1.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage.init(named: "ic_home")
 v2.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage.init(named: "ic_new")
 v3.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage.init(named: "ic_settings")

 let n1 = NavigationController.init(rootViewController: v1)
 let n2 = NavigationController.init(rootViewController: v2)
 let n3 = NavigationController.init(rootViewController: v3)

 tabBarController.shouldHijackHandler = {
    tabbarController, viewController, index in
       if index == 1 {
        return true
       }
    return false
 }

 tabBarController.didHijackHandler = {
            [weak tabBarController] tabbarController, viewController, index in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                let addQuery = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (alertAction) in
                    let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
                    let newQueryID = UUID().uuidString
                    QueryModel().createNewQuery(id: newQueryID, name: textField.text ?? "")

                    let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QueryAnalyticsController") as! QueryAnalyticsController;
                    viewController.selectedQueryID = newQueryID

                    // Then push that view controller onto the navigation stack
                    //tabBarController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
                    //tabBarController?.present(viewController, animated: true)
                }
                alert.addTextField { (textField) in
                    textField.placeholder = "Title"
                }
                alert.addAction(addQuery)
                let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(cancel)
                tabBarController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }


  tabBarController.viewControllers = [n1, n2, n3]

  self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
```

I tried

`tabBarController?.present(viewController, animated: true)`

which works but doesn't take into account the NavigationController, which I would need in order to go back.

I also tried

`tabBarController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)`

but it doesn't push the viewController as I was expecting.

Comment: dismiss the presented controller to go back why its necessary to pop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
```

with

```
self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:tabBarController)
```

As your current navigation is nil

> tabBarController?.navigationController?  <<<<< nil

OR push from the child like

```
let nav = tabBarController!.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController

nav.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Hey Sh_Khan, thanks for the answer. The first suggestion didn't work but the second did.